# Printf outside main function throws error

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a = printf("cs136/n");

int main(){
  printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

Error: (initializer element is not a compile-time constant)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use printf outside of an function. Move the line "int a = printf..." inside main.

You variable "a" is an global variable. You can only initialize "a" with an constant. For example:

```
int a = 42;

int main()
{
   a = printf(...
```